# Integral representation of the inverse distance

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics, linear-pde

I am working on the FMM method implementation. One of the important equation is the integral representation of the inverse distance
$$
\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda z} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{i \lambda (x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha)}\, d\alpha d\lambda.
$$

I want to understand, where this equation comes from? How to derive this formula? May be use Fourier transform?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the solution.

Based on the thread [Simpler proof of an integral representation of Bessel function of the first kind $J_n(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581490/simpler-proof-of-an-integral-representation-of-bessel-function-of-the-first-kind) the

$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{i\lambda(x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha)} d\alpha = J_0(\lambda\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}), 
$$
where $J_0$ is the Bessel function order zero.

It is known property of the Bessel function [Watson 1922][1]:
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-at}J_0(bt)dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}
$$

Now we have 
$$
\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-\lambda z}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\lambda(x\cos\alpha + y\sin\alpha})d\alpha d\lambda = \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda z}J_0(\lambda\sqrt{x^2+y^2})d\lambda = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \frac{1}{r}.
$$

[1]: Watson G. N. Theory of Bessel functions, 1922. Page 384.