# Nicer solution to integral $\int_0^{2\pi}\exp(A\cos x+B\sin x +ilx)dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

In my research, I am attempting to solve the following integral:
$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\exp(A\cos x+B\sin x +ilx)dx.$$ As of now, my method to solve it is as follows:

1. Use trigonometric identity $A\cos x+B\sin x=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\cos[x-\arctan(B/A)]$ to express the $\sin$ and $\cos$ as a single $\cos$,
2. Make a change of variable $y=x-\arctan(B/A)$,
3. Shift my limits of integration as needed (integrating over period of periodic function),
4. Use definition of [Bessel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581490/simpler-proof-of-an-integral-representation-of-bessel-function-of-the-first-kind): $$J_{n}(z)=\frac{e^{in\pi/2}}{2\pi} \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\large i(n\tau - z \cos{\tau})}d\tau.$$

These steps lead me to the solution:

$$2\pi J_l\left(-\sqrt{A^2+B^2}\right)e^{\large il\left[\arctan\left(\frac BA\right)-\frac\pi2\right]}.$$

The issue is that I now need to integrate this, and A and B contain variables too complicated to integrate simply, considering the term $e^{il\arctan(B/A)}$. Is there any way to simplify this last expression, or a simpler solution to my integral? Thanks!

Edit: Mathematica doesn't seem to know how to solve my integral.

Attempt to simplify: we know that $\cos(\arctan z)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}$, $\sin(\arctan z)=\dfrac{z}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}$, however, I am not aware of a formula for $\cos(l\arctan z)$, etc.

Edit 2:It doesn't seem like there is a nice way to simplify $e^{il\arctan(B/A)}$. Are there any other special functions that can be used to solve this integral?

Comment: Try using Mathematica.

Comment: $\arctan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}=-\arctan(\frac{1}{x})$

.You can simplify the exponent with this. This is probably the most simplification you can do